# Fluid Layout Issue

Tags: html, css, css-float, fluid-layout

My HTML file is.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Fluid Layout</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

</head>
<body>

 <div class="container">

     <div class="row">  

        <div class="columns four">four four four four four four four four four four four four four four four four four four four four four</div>

        <div class="columns four">four</div>

        <div class="columns four">four</div>

        <div class="columns four">four</div>

     </div><!--/row-->


    <div class="columns eight">eight</div>

    <div class="columns eight">eight</div>


    <div class="columns six">six</div>

    <div class="columns eight">eight</div>

    <div class="columns two">two</div>


    <div class="columns sixteen">sixteen</div>


 </div><!--/container-->

</body>
</html>
```

My CSS File is.

```
* {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

body {
    font: 12px/1.5em /* Notation: font-size / line height */ Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #313131;
}

.container {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: rgba(115,150,209,0.67);
}

.row {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}

.container .columns {
    float: left;
    background: tomato;
    margin: 0 0 1em;
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 1em;
    padding-left: 1em;
}

.container .columns.one          {  width: 6.25%    }
.container .columns.two          {  width: 12.5%    }
.container .columns.three        {  width: 18.75%   }
.container .columns.four         {  width: 25%      }
.container .columns.five         {  width: 31.25%   }
.container .columns.six          {  width: 37.5%    }
.container .columns.seven        {  width: 43.75%   }
.container .columns.eight        {  width: 50%      }
.container .columns.nine         {  width: 56.25%   }
.container .columns.ten          {  width: 62.5%    }
.container .columns.eleven       {  width: 68.75%   }
.container .columns.twelve       {  width: 75%      }
.container .columns.thirteen     {  width: 81.25%   }
.container .columns.fourteen     {  width: 87.5%    }
.container .columns.fifteen      {  width: 93.75%   }
.container .columns.sixteen      {  width: 100%     }


.clearfix:after,
.container:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
}

.clearfix,
.container {
    zoom: 1;
}
```

For some reason the I need to specify that anything with a class of row has a width of 100%. Shouldn't everything expand to fill the parent element?

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 0):

You're absolutely correct about your div width. By default, divs fill 100% of the width (and accommodate for padding/margin), this is because of their default css value `display:block;`. You don't need any css changes to your `.row` class.

I believe this is what you're trying to do: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VHuVg/2/)

Note that white space between your div html markup is extremely important when working with such specific width values. I've removed all white space between divs in my example (although they might not all be necessary).

Personally, I feel like there's more efficient ways to do this effect -- specifically for responsive design. If interested, let me know!